# Java in-built JSON parser

Tags: java, json

I've been working on a task where I need to make a request and get value of a specific key in JSON. Because of some limitations/complications, I'm suppose to use only in-built libraries of Java.

For making a request, I'm using `HttpURLConnection` but for parsing JSON I could not find. Could you please point me to Java in built JSON parsers.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256669/java-built-in-data-parser-for-json-or-xml-or-else) but that does not have satisfactory answer and pretty old hence asking again, in case, this is available with latest versions of Java.

Comment: AFAIK, Java does not provide any native library for processing JSON.

Answer (score 5):

There is not.

You can use built-in Nashorn engine to evaluate Javascript in Java 8

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JSONParsingTest {

    private ScriptEngine engine;

    @Before
    public void initEngine() {
        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        this.engine = sem.getEngineByName("javascript");
    }

    @Test
    public void parseJson() throws IOException, ScriptException {
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(/*path*/);
        String script = "Java.asJSONCompatible(" + json + ")";
        Object result = this.engine.eval(script);
        assertThat(result, instanceOf(Map.class));
        Map contents = (Map) result;
        contents.forEach((t, u) -> {
        //key-value pairs
        });
    }
}
```

source : [Converting JSON To Map With Java 8 Without Dependencies](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/converting_json_to_map_with)

**Update** : Nashorn has been removed from [Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372)

Comment: Yes; however, keep in mind that nashorn will be drop in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

> The Java API for JSON Processing provides portable APIs to parse,
>   generate, transform, and query JSON.

[image]

Official Website Reference - https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html

Comment: OP wants to use built-in libraries. This is an API and you would need to use a 3rd implementation library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such libraries in Java. But if you use maven, you can add [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) or [JSON-lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib) dependencies.

Comment: OP has said that he want to use only built-in libraries in Java.